# Input Validation in C When Calculating Grades

Tags: c, validation, input

I have a problem that needs to calculate the grade needed on a final exam in order to get the letter grade that they desire. I have the code correct for the calculations but I need to account for all invalid user input. I have accounted for negative grades and letter grades that don't exist but I can't figure out how to make sure the percentages they are inputting don't contain letters or other characters. For example if I ask for their current grade in the class they cannot input something like 95.6asi!. This is the code I have right now but there are many errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void calcGradeNeededOnFinal() {
  double percentWanted = 0.0;
  double currentGrade, finalWeight;
  char gradeWanted;

  printf("Enter the grade you want in the class: ");
  scanf("%c", &gradeWanted);

  if (gradeWanted == 'A' || gradeWanted == 'a'){
      percentWanted = 90.0;
  }
  else if (gradeWanted == 'B' || gradeWanted == 'b'){
      percentWanted = 80.0;
  }
  else if (gradeWanted == 'C' || gradeWanted == 'c'){
      percentWanted = 70.0;
  }
  else if (gradeWanted == 'D' || gradeWanted == 'd'){
      percentWanted = 60.0;
  }
  else if (gradeWanted == 'F' || gradeWanted == 'f'){
      percentWanted = 0.0;
  }
  else {
    printf("Unknown Grade Received: %c. Ending Program.\n", gradeWanted);
    exit(0);
}

  printf("Enter your current percent in the class: ");
  scanf("%lf", &currentGrade);

  if(currentGrade < 0) {
    printf("The number you last entered should have been positive. Ending program.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  char gradeString = (char)currentGrade;
  for(int i=0; i < strlen(gradeString); ++i) {
    if(!(isdigit(gradeString[i])) && (strcmp(gradeString[i], '.') != 0))) {
      printf("Invalid formatting. Ending program.\n");
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  printf("Enter the weight of the final: ");
  scanf("%lf", &finalWeight);

  if(finalWeight < 0) {
    printf("The number you last entered should have been positive. Ending program.\n");
    exit(0);
}
  char weightString = (char)finalWeight;
  for(int i=0; i < strlen(weightString); ++i) {
    if(!(isdigit(weightString[i])) && (strcmp(weightString[i], '.') != 0))) {
      printf("Invalid formatting. Ending program.\n");
      exit(0);
    }
  }


  // this calculates the grade need on the final test to get the desired grade of the user
  double gradeNeededOnFinal = (percentWanted - (currentGrade * (1.0 - finalWeight/100.0))) / (finalWeight/100.0);
  printf("You need to get at least %.2lf%% on the final to get a %c in the class.\n", gradeNeededOnFinal, gradeWanted);
}

int main() {
  calcGradeNeededOnFinal();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char gradeString = (char)currentGrade;` is wrong. A single character doesn't get converted to a string just because you name a variable as such. A string is a zero-terminated sequence of characters. You should be getting plenty of errors from attempting to use a single `char` variable as a string.

Comment: Can you give an example of correct input?

Comment: You should carefully read the documentation of [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html). If your compiler is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) use it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, read the documentation of GCC, and use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: You cannot use any user-input function correctly unless to ***check the return*** to verify success or failure. Otherwise you are just inviting *Undefined Behavior* in your code.

Comment: You probably should document (with a pencil and paper) the acceptable inputs, using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF) notation. Once you did that, read about [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). Notice that `scanf` returns a useful integer. Be aware of [fgetc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getc.3.html)

Comment: Study for inspiration the source code of existing open source programs (like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash) or [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler)...) and mention them to your teacher. In all cases, enable debug information and warnings in your compiler, and learn to use your debugger

Answer (score 1):

> For example if I ask for their current grade in the class they cannot input something like 95.6asi!.

You have declared grade as `char` so there is no possibility that it can store `95.6asi!`

`char gradeWanted;`

What you need is : [`isalpha`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) or `isupper` and `islower` function(s) from `ctype.h`

> isalpha() checks for an alphabetic character; in the standard "C" locale, it is equivalent to (isupper(c) || islower(c)). In some locales, there may be additional characters for which isalpha() is true-letters which are neither upper case nor lower case.

Just check if your `gradeWanted` is an alphabet or not.

Using
`if (isalpha( gradeWanted ))`
or
`if (isupper( gradeWanted ) || islower( gradeWanted ))`

is enough.

All ctype functions takes an `int` and returns an `int`, you can declare `char gradeWanted;` as `int gradeWanted;`

Answer (score 0):

you could read the characters entered and, using the ascii encoding, check (perhaps with a switch) which character is inserted and manage it.
This way you have full control of the entries.
you can get char to ascii conversion with:

`int a_as_int = (int)'a';`